# how to get data with mapActions

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I can't seem to get the data I need using mapActions from my store. I am doing an Axios GET (I turn that data to an array), and pass that data to my home.vue, and render a list of notes. 
Now, it works fine if I use mapGetters, but to my understanding, I can access data directly from mapActions, I've seen people do it, but so far I can't. Or can I?

Home.vue:

```
  export default {
  methods:{
    // Not Working
    ...mapActions(
        ['getNotes']
    ),
    created(){
    // Not working
    this.getNotes()
    console.log(this.getNotes())//returns pending Promise
  }
}
```

my store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    ...other stuff in state...
    // this is getting the notes from firebase
    notes: {}
  },
  getters: {
    ...other getters...
    notes: state => state.notes
  },
  mutations: {
    ...other mutations...
    SET_NOTES (state, notes) {
      state.notes = notes
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getNotes ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('/data.json')
        .then(res => {
          const incoming = res.data
          const notes = [] // <-- this is commited ok without explicit return
          // converting object to array
          // extracting firebase ids for manipulating existing notes
          for (let key in incoming) {
            const note = incoming[key]
            note.id = key
            notes.push(note)
          }
          console.log(notes)
          commit('SET_NOTES', notes)
          // return notes <-- tried that, no effect!
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error: ', error)
        })
    },
    ...commiting 2 other things needed for my app
  }
  ...other actions...
})
```

Comment: It should be `this.notes()`. And don't forget that your action is async one, so state will be changed _after_ your `console.log` call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you have return the notes data as a return value inside your action `getNotes()`. At the end of your success callback all you did is commit your data into the notes `commit('SET_NOTES', notes)`.

> Return your notes data

```
getNotes ({ commit }) {
  axios.get('/data.json')
    .then(res => {
      const incoming = res.data
      const notes = []
      // converting object to array
      // extracting firebase ids for manipulating existing notes
      for (let key in incoming) {
        const note = incoming[key]
        note.id = key
        notes.push(note)
        // array.reverse()
      }
      console.log(notes)
      commit('SET_NOTES', notes)
      // HERE YOU RETURN YOUR NOTES DATA
      return notes
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error: ', error)
    })
}
```

Comment: Ok, actually I had to return the whole axios request **and** the notes. I will post the answer later sometime.

Comment: @Stamatis Deliyannis If you want to return something similar to axios request structure you can return a promise.